# Application transport layer abstraction

Tags: java, nio, abstraction

I want to create an abstraction of the transport layer in my application.

I thought about encapsulating or inheriting from ServerSocketChannel and SocketChannel but very quickly I found that it's not that simple because the Java implementation uses factory methods and service providers.

My question is: what would be a good way to achieve abstraction and if it's by inheritance or encapsulation how should I do that with nio sockets?

EDIT:

By "abstraction" I mean that I would like to have some arbitrary operations that will be translated to operations on the channel. For example, a "write(message)" operation (message being of some proprietary class type) or a close() operation that also sends a shutdown message to client.

My problem with simply encapsulating the channel in my own class is that when I use a selector I get a reference to the channel and that would force me to use a lookup to access the encapsulating object. I can't do that - I must have direct access to it from the channel.

Comment: maybe you can design your own interface representing a channel.

Comment: It depends on application, on what abstraction you want or at least on logic of your code. Encapsulation and inheritance are very different. First is a "A have B" or "A includes B" and the second is "A is B".

Comment: Define 'abstraction of the transport layer'. Surely that's what `SocketChannel` already is?

Comment: Thanks for the responses. I edited my post to make it clearer. Let me know if more clarification is needed.

Comment: You can't register anything with a Selector that isn't created by the same Provider. Forget this implementation. You don't need to extend anything to accomplish that. Just use delegation.

Comment: I guess there is no easy-to-do-it-way. As I can see you want to create some asynchonous system for communication. If you want to make it on high absract level with messages, you also need to make higher level `select`. Or you could try to create some event-driven system.

Comment: @EJP That's what I meant by "encapsulation" (perhaps "delegation" would be more accurate) - I was hoping to to contain the channel within my own class and delegate to it, but then if I use a selector (on the channels) I can't reach the delegating object from the channel without a lookup.